# Best local minima given several starting points

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimum

I have several optimizers and I want to determine which optimizer describes my objective function as best as possible.

I do the following:

```
[w111, fVal111] = fmincon(fH1, x1, A, B, [], [], LB, UB, nonlcon1, o);
[w112, fVal112] = fmincon(fH2, x1, A, B, [], [], LB, UB, nonlcon2, o);
[w121, fVal121] = fmincon(fH1, x2, A, B, [], [], LB, UB, nonlcon1, o);
[w122, fVal122] = fmincon(fH2, x2, A, B, [], [], LB, UB, nonlcon2, o);
```

where I use different initial starting points and nonlinear constraints. Here `fH` is the objective function. As you can see, I am using different objective functions.

Since my function enters often into local minima, I want to know which local minima is the best.

How can I use the output (e.g. the F-values) to make such a decision?

Comment: If the value is smaller is better? That is the literal definition of what you are doing. Finding the **MINIMUM** of f

Comment: Clear. and what happens if you have alternative objective functions? Can you still compare it?

Comment: Let me clarify, the minimum, when the function is applied. Likely the minimum of `A*fval-B`

Comment: Surely the minimum of the objective function you are trying to minimise. If you knew which objective function is best, i.e. if you knew the perfect metric for the solution to be true then you would, by definition, know the answer, thus not need a minimisation function. When minimising, you just believe that your objective function is the truth, and need to deal with that. To be clear: there is no universal "this is good". And no, you can not compare different objective function values.

Comment: Why (and how) do you change your objective function and constraints to avoid a local minima? The normal approach is to use different starting points and keep all the other parameters constant.